# Manual citation alignment

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing a journal paper using "AO_JOSA_OL-LaTeX" template. However, the references are looking like the below. my question is how can I align the references?

[image]

To look like this, thanks

[image]

This is the code

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{osajnl}
\journal{ao}  
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}Reference 1
\bibitem{2}Reference 2.
\bibitem{3}Reference 3.
\bibitem{4}Reference 4.
\bibitem{5}Reference 5.
\bibitem{6}Reference 6.
\bibitem{7}Reference 7.
\bibitem{8}Reference 8.
\bibitem{9}Reference 9.
\bibitem{10}Reference 10.
\bibitem{11}Reference 11.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally, I'd expect the output to look like the second image. You need to show us the (relevant! - not all) code you use to produce the bibliography list. Please prepare an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for that. But note that you normally can't modify a journal template - after all they gave you that template to work with. If it gives sub-par output, complain to the editors of the journal. Since the template doesn't seem to use `biblatex`, I have retagged your question.

Comment: the marked references have two-digit numbers.  you have allowed for only one digit in the mandatory argument to `\begin{thebibliography}`; change that from `{1}` to `{10}` or some other two-digit number.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument in `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` gives the width of the label, so if you have two digit numbers, you should place a two digit number there.

As [barbara beeton pointed out in her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344702/manual-citation-alignment/344751#comment846079_344751) any 2 digit number should do the trick. In the special case you use a font where the digits have different widths, give the widest one, e.g. 10 and not 11.

(I don't have you documentclass, so I replaced it by article)

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{1}Reference 1
\bibitem{2}Reference 2.
\bibitem{3}Reference 3.
\bibitem{4}Reference 4.
\bibitem{5}Reference 5.
\bibitem{6}Reference 6.
\bibitem{7}Reference 7.
\bibitem{8}Reference 8.
\bibitem{9}Reference 9.
\bibitem{10}Reference 10.
\bibitem{11}Reference 11.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: typically, digits used by tex are uniform in width, so any two-digit number should suffice.  (i usually use `{99}`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton In general you should be right. I ran into this problem once with some font package (I cannot remember the name right now), so I thought rather be save then sorry...

Comment: a reasonable qualification.  something special has to be done to make numerals behave properly while being different in text and in tables; math is a bit of a wild card ...